# Converting GeoTIFF from EPSG:4326 to Spherical Mercator using QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, geotiff-tiff, gdalwarp

I'm using QGIS 3.12. I'd like to reproject NASA's Black Marble GeoTIFF (3600x1800 (0.1 degrees)) from https://earthobservatory.nasa.gov/features/NightLights/page3.php. The original projection is EPSG:4326. I would like to reproject it to EPSG:3857. Ultimately I'm going to take this reprojected GeoTiff into MapTiler to create basemap tiles.

I opened a new project in QGIS and dragged the GeoTiff onto a layer. I went to Raster > Projection > Warp, which pulled up this dialogue window:

[image]

There is no dropdown option for EPSG:3857 as a Target CRS. How might I set this target projection?

Comment: Press the Earth icon and you'll find more options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hit the button to the right of the dropdown, the globe with the hat - there you may browse and search (just enter the EPSG code) all CRS available in your QGIS.